# Indicate viewController Function for Client Side Event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

My goal is simple, all my Client side event handlers wish to be organised way in {View}Controller.js

In order to achieve the mention, I did following:

Indicate controller for view

```
     X.TreeList().ID("navTreeList")
                    .Config("controller", "navWindowController")                    
                    .Listeners(l=> { l.SelectionChange.Fn = "navTreeList_SelectionChange";  })
```

And declare function in the controller:

```
 navTreeList_SelectionChange : function (sender, event) {
    if (sender.getSelection().hasChildNodes())
        return false;
    // alert()
    return;
```

}

The good thing is that, init function of the controller is called but a navTreeList_SelectionChange event handler is not.

the reason: eventhendler not faund.

What should be done for the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution- call the controller function as regular JS function by using Handler property of the SelectionChange listener instead of Fn

```
   X.TreeList().ID("navTreeList")
                        .Config("controller", "navWindowController")                    
                        .Listeners(l=> { l.SelectionChange.Handler = "#{navTreeList}.getController().navTreeList_SelectionChange";  })
```